# A problem with my computation of the de Rham Cohomology of the 2-Sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

I already proved that 
$$
H_{p}(S^{1})=\begin{cases}
\mathbb{R} & ,p=0,1\\
0 & ,\mbox{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I now want to prove that 
$$
H_{p}(S^{2})=\begin{cases}
\mathbb{R} & ,p=0,2\\
0 & ,\mbox{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Consider the 2-sphere $S^{2}$ with poles $N=(0,0,1)$ and $S=(0,0,-1)$.
Let $U=S^{2}\backslash\{N\}$ and $V=S^{2}\backslash\{S\}$. Notice
that 
$$
U\cap V=S^{2}\backslash\{S,N\}\cong S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}\simeq S^{1}
$$

where $\cong$ denotes the homeomorphism relation and $\simeq$ denotes
the homotopy equivalence relation.

The Mayer-Vietoris Sequence is

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
0 & \rightarrow & H_{0}(S^{2}) & \rightarrow & H_{0}(U)\oplus H_{0}(V) & \rightarrow & H_{0}(U\cap V) & \rightarrow\\
 & \rightarrow & H_{1}(S^{2}) & \rightarrow & H_{1}(U)\oplus H_{1}(V) & \rightarrow & H_{1}(U\cap V) & \rightarrow\\
 & \rightarrow & ...
\end{array}
$$

Now, $H_{0}(S^{2})=\mathbb{R}$ because $S^{2}$ has one connected
component. For the same reason, $H_{0}(U)=H_{0}(V)=H_{0}(U\cap V)=\mathbb{R}$.

Also, $U$ and $V$ are homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
Hence,

$$
H_{p}(U)=H_{p}(V)=H_{p}(\mathbb{R}^{2})=\begin{cases}
\mathbb{R} & ,p=0\\
0 & ,\mbox{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

and, since $U\cap V\simeq S^{1}$, we have $H_{p}(U\cap V)=H_{p}(S^{1})$.

Thus, we can rewrite the MVS as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
0 & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R} & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R} & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R} & \rightarrow\\
 & \rightarrow & H_{1}(S^{2}) & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & H_{1}(S^{1})=\mathbb{R} & \rightarrow\\
 & \rightarrow & H_{2}(S^{2}) & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & H_{2}(S^{1})=0 & \rightarrow\\
 & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & ...
\end{array}
$$

And now I use a theorem that I read in Tu's book:

> Let $0\rightarrow A^{0}\rightarrow A^{1}\rightarrow...\rightarrow A^{m}\rightarrow0$
>   be an exact sequence of finite-dimensional vector spaces.
>   Then, 
>   $$
> \underset{k=0}{\overset{m}{\sum}}(-1)^{k}\dim A^{k}=0
> $$

In our case, if we restrict ourselves to the exact sequence
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
0 & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R} & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R} & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R} & \rightarrow\\
 & \rightarrow & H_{1}(S^{2}) & \rightarrow & 0 & \rightarrow & H_{1}(S^{1})=\mathbb{R} & \rightarrow\\
 & \rightarrow & H_{2}(S^{2}) & \rightarrow & 0
\end{array}
$$
we get

$$
1-2+1-x_{1}+0-1+x_{2}=0
$$

with $x_{1}=\dim H_{1}(S^{2})$ and $x_{2}=\dim H_{2}(S^{2})$.

So 
$$
x_{2}-x_{1}=1
$$

One option is obviously $x_{2}=1$ and $x_{1}=0$. But how can I show
that the other options are incorrect? Also, just because $\dim H_{2}(S^{2})$
does that mean that $H_{2}(S^{2})=\mathbb{R}$? (I think I saw this
argument being made before). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your long exact sequence is
$$0\to H^1(S^1)=\Bbb R\to H^2(S^2)\to0.$$
This already shows that $H^1(S^1)$ and $H^2(S^2)$ are isomorphic,
so $x_2=1$.

Comment: I see. Could you please answer the other question?

Comment: @Simoes which other question?

Comment: After "Also..."

Comment: And another thing: Another part of my sequence is 
$$
      0\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \rightarrow H_1(S^2) \rightarrow 0
$$
So by your argument $x_1$ is also equal to $1$, it seems...

Comment: No, that isn't part of your sequence: before $\Bbb R$ there comes $\Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R$, not $0$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks. Still, the other question remains: just because $\dim H_{2}(S^{2})$
does that mean that $H_{2}(S^{2})=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What $H^2(S^2)$ is, is a 1-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$. Whether or not such a thing **is** $\Bbb R$ is very much up to one's own opinion.